# J2me nokia touch device

Tags: java-me, touch, device, nokia

My midlet does not wake up on touching the screen, it does wake up on pressing some device button. To add more information, I am using Nokia 5230.

Comment: Check if your have implemented some code in `showNotify()` in the current displayable `Canvas`. 

**PS:** I am assuming you are developing using native UI code and not using any 3rd party UI libraries. In which case the solution would be different, so let me know.

Comment: Hmm.. He wakes up, if you press the button. Imho: the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: May be [this post][1] could help you. I relates to the same problem I think.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101075/dont-let-the-display-go-to-stand-by-in-javame

Comment: @SergeyZubkow, please confirm whether you are waking up the device by pressing unlock screen or power hardware key? If that is so the devices' screen idle/lock setting is putting the device to sleep mode. In which case 'pheromix' pointed link would help you.

Comment: Yes, the device waking up by pressing unlock screen or power hardware key. My device is stops receive messages from pressing on the screen. That is, I need to sleep and wake up the device from clicking on the screen. Mini Opera is doing.

Comment: @SergeyZubkow, If that is so than `pheromix` link will help. Have you tried it ?

Comment: @Vimal Yes, it does not help.

Comment: are you using any kind of GUI like j2mepolish or LWUIT ?